# Python serial script prevents android connection

Tags: python, serial, bluetooth, android

The python script below connects via "rfcomm0" to the "Bluefruit EZ-link module" on the "Arduino Uno" but prevents the bluetooth connection from my android app. If I change the script to use "/dev/ttyACM0" all is well.

"serial_test.py" contains

```
import serial
1) ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
2) ser = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm',9600)
while True:
print ser.readline()
```